# javascript canvas rain simulator

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, simulator

Hello im trying to create javascript rain generator based on canvas but im stuck with generating new dropes. I have nothing but canvas element in HTML and css so im attaching only JS script.

```
 <script>
        const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        canvas.width = 1000;
        canvas.height = 500;

        const cw = canvas.width;
        const ch = canvas.height;

        const dropSize = 5;
        //drop actual position
        let dropX = Math.floor((Math.random() * cw) + 1); 
        let dropY = 0 ;
        //something that will trigger creation of anothers drop
        let dropTrigger = 400;


        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*1) + 1; // 
        num *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1; // random direction of X btw (-1 and 1) How to implement this?

        //speed controls direction of drops 
        let dropSpeedX = num; //in the future will base on random
        let dropSpeedY = 3;  //in the future will base on random

        //function which creates one drop basing on start coordinates (X,Y)
        function createDrop() {
            ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
            ctx.fillRect(dropX, dropY, dropSize, dropSize);
            //current position on the screen
            dropX += dropSpeedX;
            dropY += dropSpeedY;
            if(dropY >= dropTrigger){
                dropY=0;
            }
        }
        //background creator
        function createBackground(){

            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
        }

        //whole simulator
        function play(){
            createBackground();
            createDrop();
        }

        //interval paints everything on the screen in 30fps

        setInterval(play, 1000/ 30);
</script>
```

Now I am able to create only one falling drop at one time. Have anyone some idea how to ,,generate" another drops (many at the same time) and how to implement that change of X direction where i putted "???"marks in comment? It works well only when im refreshing the browser.
Huge thanks in advance

Comment: Set interval is not what you should be using, see requestAnimationFrame

Comment: thank you i have changed that ;). something about the logical problems plss ;PP